# Python Dictionary to CSV file but as a (key:value) seperated lines

Tags: python, html

so I have created a dictionary of a crawler than checks html files and looks for "href=" phrase that targets to an other html file/s.

So the dictionary looks like this:

```
{'1.html': ['2.html', '3.html'], '2.html': ['3.html', '4.html'], '3.html': ['5.html', '7.html'], '5.html': [], '7.html': ['2.html'], '4.html': ['6.html'], '6.html': ['2.html']}
```

I would like to create a CSV file from this dictionary.
I want it to be organised as separated lines for each key:value by this design:

```
key,value1a,value1b
key2,value2a,value2b
```

for eg:

```
1.html,2.html,3.html
2.html,3.html,4.html
and etc
```

so this is supposed to be very easy, I did manage to create a csv file that looks like:

```
> 1.html,['2.html', '3.html']
> 2.html,['3.html', '4.html']
> 3.html,['5.html', '7.html']
> 5.html,[]
> 7.html,['2.html']
> 4.html,['6.html']
> 6.html,['2.html']
```

using the code:

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    [f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value)) for key, value in dic.items()]
```

But now I have to remove the brackets and the "," after keys without any value attached to them(for example: 5.html).

So I thought about making an if statement that will check whether the value exists or not.
If it does, the print will go by "key,value"
if it doesn't, the print will go by only "key"

```
This is my code:
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in dic.items:
        if value:
            f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value))
        else:
            f.write('{0}\n'.format(key))
```

and then I thought to write a loop that goes through every line and checks for the brackets and removes them.
Yeah I know I probably wrote it all wrong, so i'll be glad to know where are my mistakes.
Thanks.

Comment: Do **not** use list comprehensions for side effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join command with your key as below:

```
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f: 
    for key, value in dic.items: 
        if value: 
            f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, ",".join(value)))
        else: 
            f.write('{0}\n'.format(key))
```

Comment: Thank you! Good to know that I knew at least how to define an if statement and got wrong only with the "join" thing. it works.

Comment: Thanks, Leave an upvote if you found your question answered and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
[f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, ",".join(value))) for key, value in dic.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write something like this:

```
def print_dict(d, file):
    for key in d.keys():
        file.write(key)
        for item in d[key]:
            file.write("," + item)
        file.write("\n")
```

where file is the file you created and d is the dictionary you created
and it will print the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I would use `print` function for that task following way:

```
dct = {'1.html': ['2.html', '3.html'], '2.html': ['3.html', '4.html'], '3.html': ['5.html', '7.html'], '5.html': [], '7.html': ['2.html'], '4.html': ['6.html'], '6.html': ['2.html']}
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for k,v in dct.items():
        print(k, *v, sep=',', file=f)
```

`my_file.csv` content:

```
1.html,2.html,3.html
2.html,3.html,4.html
3.html,5.html,7.html
5.html
7.html,2.html
4.html,6.html
6.html,2.html
```

`*` denotes so called unpacking

Comment: thanks alot. I did not know what "*" means in python but I read about it and I almost fully understood your answer. Thanks. It still not really clear to me tho what "*" means .